# iOS Objective c - set uiviewcontroller to feed screen after user login then relaunch app

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

i have this login page screen that shows in the first load.

Then when the user enters his password and username, it will redirect to the feed screen.

My question is:

- How can i set the screen to feed screen when the user kills and relaunch the app given that he already logged in?

it always loads the login screen. Help me please! I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user haven't logged in, you can present `loginViewController` on `feedViewController` **without any animation**. So the `loginViewController` will cover the `feedViewController`.

```
if (!loggedIn) {
    feedViewController.present(loginViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

If the user is already logged in, you don't need to do anything since the `feedViewController` is the main view controller. So the user will see `feedViewController` if they are already logged in.

To complete the answer, after the user input their username and password and the login succeed, you can dismiss the `loginViewController` **with animation** and it will give nice slide down animation and showing the `feedViewController` behind it.

```
loginViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```